# PHP PDO Multiple queries doesnt get any value

Tags: php, pdo

I already did inner join before this code but then it seems like every time i have multiple queries it doesnt work. But then when I did it single query it seems fine and working. Please help me experts. Thank you!

```
<?php
include('db.php');
include('function.php');
if(isset($_POST["personal_info_id"]))
{
    $id1 = $_POST["personal_info_id"];
    $id2 = $_POST["personal_info_id"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM hr_details WHERE personal_info_id = '$id1'";
    $sql .="SELECT * FROM personal_info WHERE personal_info_id = '$id2'";
    $output = array();  
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $output["firstname"] = $row["firstname"];
        $output["middlename"] = $row["middlename"];
        $output["lastname"] = $row["lastname"];
        $output["address"] = $row["address"];
        $output["birthdate"] = $row["birthdate"];
        $output["gender"] = $row["gender"];
        $output["religion"] = $row["religion"];
        $output["civil_status"] = $row["civil_status"];
        $output["biometrics"] = $row["biometrics"];
        if($row["image"] != '')
        {
        $output['user_image'] = '<img src="upload/'.$row["image"].'" class="img-thumbnail" width="50" height="35" /><input type="hidden" name="hidden_user_image" value="'.$row["image"].'" />';
        }
        else
        {
          $output['user_image'] = '<input type="hidden" name="hidden_user_image" value="" />';
         }

    }

    echo json_encode($output);

}
?>
```

Comment: This `PDO` is same as not using a `PDO`. Why on the earth you are not binding your parameter when you are using `PDO`. Secondly, It is a straight error in SQL. You're combining two queries without terminating the first one through `;`

Comment: Its because i need to get values from two different table with same "personal_info_id'

Comment: Then terminate the first one through `;` and $id1 will be treated as $id1 in sql because "" doesn't allow parsing variable use '' try this: `"SELECT * FROM hr_details WHERE personal_info_id = '".$id1."';"`

Comment: I don't understand why you really need multiple select statements in this situation (It looks like INNER JOIN is the way to go). And also you should definitely use parameter binding since you have chosen the PDO path in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's possible to run [multiple queries in one call with PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#multiquery), **there is not a single reason to do so**. Neither your case is an exception. It will never work as you think. Instead of stuffing several queries in one call like this, you need a single query with JOIN.

Another issue with your code is a **cargo cult prepared statement**. It looks like a real one but protects nothing. You should use parameters in your prepared query.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM hr_details hd, personal_info pi WHERE 
        hd.personal_info_id=pi.personal_info_id AND hd.personal_info_id=?";
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute([$_POST["personal_info_id"]]);
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Is it also the same with UPDATE?

Comment: yes. for the update you must be using single prepare multiple execute

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't that work by doing this?

```
SELECT * FROM hr_details hd, personal_info pi WHERE hd.personal_info_id=pi.personal_info_id AND personal_info_id = id
```

You must be careful not to pass the variables directly in the SQL query, by using prepare

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM hr_details hd, personal_info pi WHERE hd.personal_info_id=pi.personal_info_id AND personal_info_id = :id';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':id' => $_POST["personal_info_id"]));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Comment: why not to add an example code to your answer instead of just giving a link?

Comment: I just added :)

Comment: Is it also the same as updating a query?

Comment: Yes, it's the same